# Shower Door Broke

Tags: doors, shower

My shower door has shattered and my lease is almost up. Its very important that there not be anything wrong with my place and shower doors are so expensive.

What's a good solution?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm not sure what your question is (how can you conceal the damage? how can you convince your landlord that a cheap door is actually an expensive door? how can you replace a door with a curtain and have your landlord not notice?). In any case, this probably isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can prove it, but some doors have been known to shatter on their own. Same with car windows. I'd explain the situation to the landlord.

Comment: Without seeing it, there is no way to know. It depends whether the door has a permanent from or one which can have the glass replaced. Any solution will probably cost over $1000.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have four options.  None of them are really better then the other as each has it merits so what is a good solution is what best fits your abilities and pocket book.  But if it looks wrong, you could be billed for repairs in the end.

Completely replace the door and frame with a new one.  Takes the most work and skill level to install.  And you would need to find a reasonable matching replacement.

Replace the door part of the existing (if model is still available) with one from the same model.  This saves from having to mount an all new frame.

Take the broken door part to a local glass shop and have them replace the glass section with proper type glass.

Last would be just report it to your lease management and work with them on how they would like to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the door ends up being more than your deposit and the home is in really good shape it may be worth it to have it replaced if you plan on renting in the future. Many owners including me don't remember exactly what the door looks like but if it is gone will direct the agency that took care of the rental ECT to provide a bad reference.